# Difference between 食事をする and 食事を食べる

Tags: words

I came across the following sentence:

> 駅の近くで食事をした。

Does it sound unnatural if I were to use the following (or rather, is it incorrect)?

> 駅の近くで食事を食べました。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 「[駅]{えき}の[近]{ちか}くで[食事]{しょくじ}を[食]{た}べました。」

is grammatical but the 「食事を食べる」 part is redundant and unnatural because  「食事」 already means "eating a meal" all by itself.  It is not something that more careful speakers would say.

「食事をした/しました」 or 「食事を[取]{と}った/取りました」 would sound far "better".

It is like saying 「ロペスさんが[日本]{にほん}に[来日]{らいにち}した。」.  It says "Japan" twice in such a short sentence when 「来日」, all by itself, means "coming to Japan".

A more proper way to say it is: 「ロペスさんが来日した。」 or 「ロペスさんが日本に[来]{き}た。」